# I'm having an issue in sculpting where an item becomes invisible but is still physically there

Tags: modeling, sculpting

[image]At the moment I am working on the blender guru's level one tutorials. I have gotten to part 5 and have run into an issue: Whenever I switch over to the sculpt tab, the doughnut disappears. I know it is there because it shows up in the collection tab, and if I move my cursor over it, it will show along the surface of it, and if I select it, it has an outline.

So far, I have tried <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> on both the sculpt tab and layout tab with no results. I've hit the <kbd>/</kbd> key on the sculpt tab, though it did not seem to do anything (I might be using it wrong I've only been using Blender for about a day).

I've pulled up an entirely new blender project and went to sculpt immediately with the same result a blank screen with the object being invisible, but I can still interact with it. I will try to clear any confusion up if you are trying to help me. Maybe this image can give some further context.

[image]

Comment: Each Workspace has different View Settings under the "N" menu.
Maybe this is a clipping issue?

Comment: @TreyHarper the clipping start is set at 0.1m. is this what you were meaning?

Comment: Hmmm...  Doesn't seem to be a clipping issue.  You should upload your .blend file so others can take a look at it.  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @TreyHarper ok here is the .blend file. hopefully, this will help.

Comment: Opened the file and it looks fine.  I see the image correctly.  Played around with every setting I can thing of- Sorry!  Maybe someone else will have an idea.

Comment: thank you for trying @TreyHarper you did what you could.

Comment: @TreyHarper could it be any thing to do with the mask?

Comment: Just saw this. Might be related?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159809/object-completely-disappears-in-sculpt

Comment: @TreyHarper I can't say that it worked due to the factor I just updated to V1.83 and it fixed the problem so I couldn't try anything on the post. thank you for the help that you have provided. Also, how do I compensate you for the assistance?

Comment: Stay active on the site, learn as much as you can, and pay it forward.